# How to determine certificate verification error

Tags: python, error-handling, openssl, pyopenssl

I have a bespoke HTTP/S client (based on twisted.HTTPClient) which connects to real-world servers, so I need to handle bad certificates.

When I connect to https://expired.badssl.com I receive an OpenSSL.SSL.Error with args/message of [('SSL routines', 'SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE', 'certificate verify failed')]. So far so good..!

In my case I need to handle certificate errors in a particular way, so how do I disambiguate this type of SSL.Error from others? 
The only way I can find is to do a string compare... which feels... wrong.

Comment: In the case of OpenSSL proper, you would call [`SSL_get_verify_result`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/ssl/SSL_get_verify_result.html) to get the success/failure status. In the case of failure, the code would denote an expired certificate, an untrusted path/chain, etc. Note the links on the man pages appear somewhat bent. Here's the link to the [`verify` app](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/apps/verify.html) with the reasons/error codes.  I'm not sure what you do in Python.  Also see [SSL/TLS Client](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/SSL/TLS_Client) on the OpenSSL wiki.

Answer (score 0):

> The only way I can find is to do a string compare... 
>   which feels... wrong.

I think that is the only approach.

`OpenSSL.SSL.Error` is the base class for SSL exceptions.  AFAIK, when it is raised directly, the only way to disambiguate the type of error is by comparing the reason inside the error message tuple.

from pyopenssl docs:

*"Whenever this exception is raised directly, it has a list of error messages from the OpenSSL error queue, where each item is a tuple (lib, function, reason). Here lib, function and reason are all strings, describing where and what the problem is"*

see:
https://pyopenssl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/ssl.html#OpenSSL.SSL.Error